# PHP command line: automatically populate input from executed function

Tags: php, command-line

I've been struggling on this problem for a few days now.

Before we start, this is not about getting git to work.
It just so happens that it's a good example of the problem.
The problem is how to enter data into an executed function.

I’m writing a script to automatically push code to a git server. I’m using php and running the script via the command line. After asking the user to enter the branch and commit message, the following code runs:

```
exec(‘git config user.name "’ . $userName . ‘"’);
exec(‘git config user.email "’ . $userEmail . ‘"’);

exec('git checkout -b ’ . $branch);
exec(‘git add --all’);
exec(‘git commit -m "’ . $message . ‘"’);

exec('git push origin ’ . $branch);
```

When running the last command, the script stops and asks for a user name, then a password. How can I enter that username and password via the script? I don’t want to have to type in the user name and password each time. As I said, I've been stuck on this for 2 days now.

I tried other forums, searching the net.

I'm frustrated...

Thanks in advance. Have a lovely day.

Comment: You possibly need to switch to [proc_open()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) so you can provide data via STDIN.

Comment: Thanks Alvaro. I appreciate your answer. I'm actually looking at proc_open() at the moment, but I can't get it to work. It still gets stuck when the user name is requested. Have you got a practical example of how to do this?

Comment: Would it not be possible to [use an SSH key](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh) to eliminate the need for logging in every time?

Comment: Yes, but that's not the objective. The objective is to learn how to pass input into the executed function.